# Set payload on Lambda Invoke request for AWS C++ SDK

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

Is it possible to set a payload on a Lambda Invoke request for the AWS C++ SDK? When looking at the [docs](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_lambda_1_1_model_1_1_invoke_request.html) it appears as though this may not be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

The `InvokeRequest` class does not directly provide a method for setting the payload. However, it's super class `Aws::AmazonWebServiceRequest` provides a method `SetBody` which can be used for setting the payload.

AWS has provided an example of how this is done [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/cpp/example_code/lambda/lambda_example.cpp)

Comment: after lots of time spent on this, you saved my day :)